# Does nobody answer questions on this site?

Tags: discussion

[My last question](https://superuser.com/q/733473/287352) got nothing at all. Not even a comment or anything.

I'm not sure if [my most recent question](https://superuser.com/q/734939/287352) will get anything either. I looked at the most recent pages of questions (about 12 hours past). Most of them have no answers and no upvotes, but there are so many.

Is this site still healthy? Can I expect to get answers, or is it hit and miss? Are there really only people asking and not to many answering?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your question topics, I assume there's a good chance that the Dw shortcut isn't (easily) configurable and Youtube reserves speech recognition for videos; so it's likely that the correct answer to both is "*No, it is not possible*" -- [I've posted similar answers before](http://superuser.com/a/329717), but for your particular questions, it's would be near impossible to provide definitive negative answers with evidence, as they're about commercial closed-source software and online service (an FAQ entry helps, or asking the vendor, but that can also be misleading).

Answer (score 8):

People answer questions they are able to answer. It's really as simple as that.

Comment: It's more than just no answers. There's no activity at all. I don't mind not getting an answer; the two I linked I suspect don't have one anyway. But you get no votes and no comments either, see that is common on a bunch of recent questions and you start to wonder if they are even being seen/read at all.

Comment: it's pointless to leave a comment as "lolz idk not answering"

Answer (score 1):

I once had several questions on SU/SV and got hardly any replies/activity on them, too.

Then, I linked them in a comment on Scott Hanselman's blog (as they were suitable in the context to link) and got dramatically more views and answers.

So my conclusion would be to heavily use the "Share" link below your questions to make them visible outside the SX network (e.g. on your Facebook page or on Twitter or Google+)

Answer (score -1):

This is actually the first question that I've answered.

Comment: But did you actually answer it?

Comment: @fredsbend I clicked the "Post Your Answer" button. IS THIS THING ON?